# Could not resolve type name: frontmedia.core.sitecoreextension.search.customindex, frontmedia.core.sitecoreextension

Tags: sitecore

When i work on sitecore with tds i got this error. How can i resolve this problem?

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not resolve type name:
>   frontmedia.core.sitecoreextension.search.customindex,
>   frontmedia.core.sitecoreextension
>   (method:
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateType(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters,
>   Boolean assert)).  Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error
>   and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Exception:
>   Could not resolve type name:
>   frontmedia.core.sitecoreextension.search.customindex,
>   frontmedia.core.sitecoreextension
>   (method:
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateType(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters,
>   Boolean assert)).
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [Exception: Could not resolve type
>   name:
>   frontmedia.core.sitecoreextension.search.customindex,
>   frontmedia.core.sitecoreextension
>   (method:
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateType(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters,
>   Boolean assert)).]
>   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Error.Raise(String
>   error, String method) +129
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateType(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters,
>   Boolean assert) +421
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters,
>   Boolean assert) +67
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters,
>   Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
>   +141    Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String
>   configPath, String[] parameters,
>   Boolean assert) +424
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromReference(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters,
>   Boolean assert) +194
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters,
>   Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
>   +118    Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode
>   paramNode, String[] parameters,
>   Boolean assert) +930
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters,
>   Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean
>   deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +581 
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters,
>   Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
>   +296    Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String
>   configPath, String[] parameters,
>   Boolean assert) +424
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase(String
>   name, Boolean assert) +185
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabases()
>   +152    Sitecore.Data.Managers.HistoryManager.InitializeEventHandlers()
>   +49    Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeManagers.Process(PipelineArgs
>   args) +9    (Object , Object[] ) +80
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs
>   args) +191
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start()
>   +146    Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication
>   app) +603
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers) +546
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState
>   state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +325 
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +407 
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +375
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not
>   resolve type name:
>   frontmedia.core.sitecoreextension.search.customindex,
>   frontmedia.core.sitecoreextension
>   (method:
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateType(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters,
>   Boolean assert)).]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +11529072
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +141
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +4784373
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET
>   Version:4.0.30319.1

Comment: I have the same problem, something is wrong with app.config...

Comment: Dang it. Same error and was hoping there was a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you need to add a reference to the frontmedia.core.sitecoreextension assembly in your project folder for your build. Look in you bin for the dll named frontmedia.core.sitecoreextension. In Solution Explorer in VS, select References (make sure to show all files and folders). Right click to open the context menu. Select Add Reference...In the dialog, select the Browse tab. Broswe to the bin folder of the website. Select the frontmedia.core.sitecoreextension.dll. Click OK. In properties, set copylocal to false. Build.  There may be other extensions, too. Look in the App_Config/Include folder to what other extensions are referrenced. For example, look at XslExtension.config for named classes and assemblies.  If using TDS from Hedge Hog, you'll probably need to add this to your build server as well.

Comment: +1, exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: The problem is, frontmedia.core.sitecoreextension.dll is not in the bin folder.